# DHCP Server IP Conflict Detection

Tags: wifi, ip, dhcp, access-point

I am setting an Wifi Access point. A common problem about this is that router or etc. could be giving similar IP address to client devices which will cause problems.

My question here is that is there a proper way to handle DHCP IP conflict in software (Handling DHCP IP)? The manual way is to set my access point to a different IP which I am trying to prevent.

If there is none, how straight forward would it be to implement a program that does conflict detection?

Comment: Are you using more than one router? If you are using just one, then the router itself won't assign the same IP twice. If you are looking to avoid colissions due to connection failures and two computers vi'ing for the same IP slowing your network, you could just use a DHCP reservation table within the router.

Answer (score 3):

Routers (or your DHCP server) keeps a table of leased out IP addresses and refers to that table when a device requests a new IP address from your router/dhcp server. Unless the DHCP server is configured incorrectly, there is very minimal chance of IP collision. Still, in order to avoid this scenario, I'd set the static IP's on the devices which are permanent in your network (such as AP's, printers, servers, IP cameras, centralized storage etc.)

In case you don't have an option to set static IP's, you can use something called `DHCP static lease` which is configured on the router/dhcp server. Basically, you tell your router that if a request for an IP address comes from a specific `MAC addr`, give `this IP` to that device. When this is configured, the IP address on mentioned device will not change. I don't know which router you are specifically using, but all the new ones should have this option. Finding `MAC addr` is easy, every device which has a network interface, should have this `MAC addr` printed on the back (or side).

A quick google search for `DHCP static lease` shows many results such as: https://www.howtogeek.com/69612/how-to-set-up-static-dhcp-on-your-dd-wrt-router/

Comment: If you have unregistered access points (i.e. couple of non commercial APs), how would you resolve it? I was hoping that there would be a specific setting/configuration in DHCP.

Comment: See my answer (edited) above

Comment: DHCP static lease sounds good but what if you are expecting random client devices? I just want an always unique IP to give the client devices.